# post to a remote server using cURL from a server using proxy/firewall

Tags: php, post, curl, wordpress, firewall

I am developing a wordpress plugin which post data to a remote server using cURL.
This works fine on maximum websites but on some websites it just come up with an ERROR ACCESS DENIED.

```
    [headers] => Array
    (
        [server] => squid/3.3.8
        [mime-version] => 1.0
        [date] => Tue, 31 Mar 2015 07:32:51 GMT
        [content-type] => text/html
        [content-length] => 3406
        [x-squid-error] => ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0
        [vary] => Accept-Language
        [content-language] => en
        [x-cache] => MISS from hproxy2.world4you.com
        [x-cache-lookup] => NONE from hproxy2.world4you.com:3128
        [via] => 1.1 hproxy2.world4you.com (squid/3.3.8)
        [connection] => close
    )
```

Above is the response which I am geting.

Below is the code which I am using

```
    function testpost($ac,$d_name,$an,$data) {
        $fields = '';
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        }

        rtrim($fields, '&');
    $post = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $ac);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    $result = curl_exec($post);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";      

}
```

Also, on some server it  keep executing and not return anything. For these not able to figuring out what's the issue and even not able to show user some error message because it does not return anything.

e.g.
If I install the plugin on abc.com and try to POST using cURL to xyz.com/test.php,  in test.php I have written the code to wirte data into text file to check the cURL request from  abc.com  is reaching on xyz.com or not. But it does not write anything into text file means request is not reaching from abc.com to xyz.com. In this I does not get any response and it keep executing on abc.com for a long time.

So, I need help in finding out what's creating this problem and how I can POST data from abc.com to xyz.com

Comment: Do I have  to modify my plugin to get server proxy settings(on which plugin running). e.g.   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxyPort);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxyIp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $loginpassw);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Websites or Server where you are running your plugin is behind a firewall and hence it is blocking your cURL request. To overcome this user's of this plugin has to pass their server proxy setting.
See below-

```
    function testpost($ac,$d_name,$an,$data,$proxy_ip,$proxy_port,$login_passw) {
    $fields = '';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }

    rtrim($fields, '&');
$post = curl_init();
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $ac);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $login_passw);
$result = curl_exec($post);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

}

Comment: Thank You Rajinder. But do every users have to contact their hosting support in order to get details about their poxy settins?

Comment: Yes, if they don't know then they have to.

Answer (score 0):

squid (the proxy) is blocking your request. Go look in squid's logs why is it blocking the request.

Comment: Yes, It is pretty clear from the response array that some Proxy/Firewall (squid ) is blocking my request, but this is the case for only one server and many case it keeps executing and doesn't not return  any thing. In this how I can over come over this?

Comment: In short I know what is creating this problem, but I need solution to overcome this. I think this can be overcome by passing cURL proxy setting(host,port,username,password). But as many users are going to use this plugin on different servers and many of them will not know about these type of settings(host,port,username,password). Do they all required to contact their hosting support in order to get these  cURL proxy Details?